# symbols display wrong in `screen` - ascii or utf

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, character-encoding

I don't know since when and why :

```
$ mkdir -p a/b/c x/y/{1,2,3}
$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── b
│       └── c
└── x
    └── y
        ├── 1
        ├── 2
        └── 3

8 directories, 0 files
```

when I run screen, displays symbols full of question marks:

```
$ screen
<-- screen starts... -->
$ tree
.
��� a
�   ��� b
�       ��� c
��� x
    ��� y
        ��� 1
        ��� 2
        ��� 3

8 directories, 0 files
```

Similarly for utf characters.

Even if I move away my `.screenrc` (e.g. with `mv -v ~/.screenrc{,.bak}` ) it's still strange characters set.

It happens on screen on my main user, on root user, but on my secondary user it does not. On this one characters work properly in screen. And it's not `.screenrc` as I played with it.

Updates:

Re: $TERM - seems unrelated

- without screen: TERM==xterm-256color
- user A inside screen: TERM==screen.xterm-256color and display incorrectly
- user B inside screen: TERM==screen.xterm-256color and display correctly

Re: `defutf8 on` - does something

After adding `defutf8 on` in `.screenrc` there is now mix ;p some symbols work some don't, example :

```
$ tree
.
├── a
│�� └── b
│��     └── c
└── x
    └── y
        ├── 1
        ├── 2
        └── 3

8 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: When I do the same on Ubuntu 20.10 I do not see any difference between outputs.  `screen` does not change anything to the appearance of Terminal although it is in the ps list. Screen version 4.08.00 (GNU) 05-Feb-20

Comment: Check the values of `$TERM` in both environments. Try using the `$TERM` value from your working environment.

Comment: Do you have `defutf8 on` in your ~/.screenrc?  or run `screen` with `-U`?   BTW, it has been a long time since I used screen, but I vaguely remember that disappointment with its utf handling was one of the reasons i switched to `tmux`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments in my original question, they helped me to narrow troubleshooting and find that this one line in my `~/.bashrc` is the cause - locale staff I guess:

```
export LC_PAPER=a4
```

with this line, e.g. `tree` displays correctly without `screen` but incorrectly inside `screen`.

After removing this line from `.bashrc` it looks good again.

Comment: Still - anyone with idea how to make it work despite `LC_PAPER=a4` ? :P

Comment: Your paper size can be found in `/etc/papersize` - this would normally contain 'a4'.

There is also a file `/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_PAPER` which contains unprintable data.

Neither file should be referenced in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: use `screen -U` solved a similar display problem in screen terminal.