# How to set `export LC_PAPER=a4` to not break apps?

Tags: bash, locale, unicode, printer

I had to remove `export LC_PAPER=a4` from my `~/.bashrc`  as it was breaking characters display in `screen` and some other apps : [symbols display wrong in `screen` - ascii or utf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646177/symbols-display-wrong-in-screen-ascii-or-utf) .

Therefore, question, how to set `a4` as default page size (so it's default e.g. in Chrome and other apps) without breaking things ?

No, I don't want to change whole country/language locale. I wan to change `LC_PAPER` only -> is it possible to make it in non breaking fashion? What have I missed?

Comment: Read `man lpoptions`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LC_PAPER` shouldn’t be set to an actual paper size, it should be set to a locale from which the paper size will be determined.

Since you want A4:

```
export LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
```

You can check the settings with `locale -k LC_PAPER`:

```
$ locale -k LC_PAPER
height=297
width=210
paper-codeset="UTF-8"
```

For completeness, it’s worth noting that [`LC_PAPER` is a GNU extension](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html), [not supported in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_02).